# Bibliography in the TOC of a book class without numbering

Tags: table-of-contents, bibliographies

I'm using a template for a thesis, and it's a book class document. I'm adding bibliography with those two commands:

```
\bibliography{bibliografia}
\bibliographystyle{apalike}
```

and it reads the `bibliograpfia.bib` file with bibtex items inside. It does not appear into the Table of Content.

So, I have only added `\usepackage[nottoc,numbib]{tocbibind}` at it appears on the TOC. Good!

But.. it is numbered as 5 (I have 4 chapters). How to report bibliography without the numbering?

Comment: Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From `tocbibind` documentation (page 2):

[image]

Hence `numbib` numbers the bibliography in the toc. Remove that option:

```
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
```

You should be good to go.

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
\begin{document}
    \newpage
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliography}
    \bibliography{your_bibTeX_file}

\end{document}
```

Your bibliography shows up in the TOC, without the chapter numbering.